# Return a single record from a list of records in Elm

Tags: elm

I’m trying to return a single record from a list of records when a condition is met.
Right now I’m returning a record with empty fields when the condition is false.

Is this OK?
Is there a better way?

```
xs =
    [ { name = "Mike", id = 1 }
    , { name = "Paul", id = 2 }
    , { name = "Susan", id = 3 }
    ]


getNth id xs =
    let
        x =
            List.filter (\i -> i.id == id) xs
    in
        case List.head x of
            Nothing ->
                { name = "", id = 0 }

            Just item ->
                item
```

Comment: If it's working, then probably it's fine, no?

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly your question, but maybe you're looking for http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.1/Maybe

Comment: @Edvin Tenovim Yeah it's working but I feel that I'm doing too much work. That's why I thought that maybe there is an easier/idiomatic way that I'm missing.

Comment: @JoseOrtega why don't you just return `List.filter (\i -> i.id == id) xs` as a `Maybe Item` and then handle the cases in your calling function?

Comment: Well, Maybe :) But then for using the result in another function I would have to check for this maybe with another case expression, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no search function for lists in the core `List` package, but the community has one in the [List-Extra](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/2.0.0/List-Extra#find). With this function, the above program can be written:

```
import List.Extra exposing (find)

getNth n xs =
  xs 
  |> find (.id >> (==) n)
  |> Maybe.withDefault { id = n, name = "" }
```

The canonical way to handle the "there might not be a value" in Elm is to return a `Maybe` value—this way, the user of `getNth` can choose what should be done when the value he is looking for cannot be found. So I'd prefer to leave out the last line, arriving at the very neat:

```
getNth n = find (.id >> (==) n)
```

Comment: Well, I went for a solution simliar to @marcosh `List.filter (\i -> i.id == id) xs` but I'm going to mark this as an accepted answer because it gives another perspective. Thank you.